# having trouble with 2D Player movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hallo Stackoverflow community.
I am a person new to coding and C#. I started working on a jump and run game and while coding the movent system i dont know what is wrong white the code. (i use Visual studio)
The errocode is

> error CS0103: The name 'Moved' does not exist in the current context

And my Code is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);      
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, the error does not reflect the code - in other words: this code will not produce that error. Can you show the actual error or code?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to access a variable `Moved` in the script where it doesn't exist. Make sure you have created the variable and have written the variable name with the correct casing.